# .NET Core Singleton Session Wrapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, singleton, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to create a Session Wrapper class for ASP.NET Core Razor Pages.

In traditional ASP.NET web forms my singleton session wrapper class used to work normally, but i am not sure if in .net core it will work the same or the same class will be shared across all requests.
I want to store specific information for each request (session) and not to be shared across all requests.

i created the following wrapper :

```
public class MySession
{
    //the ISession interface mandatory
    public ISession Session { get; set; }


    private static MySession instance;

    private MySession() {
    }

    public static MySession Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new MySession();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }


    //properties
    public User User
    {
        get => SessionHelper.SessionExtensions.Get<User>(this.Session, "User");
        set => SessionHelper.SessionExtensions.Set<User>(this.Session, "User", value);
    }
    public bool LoggedIn
    {
        get => SessionHelper.SessionExtensions.Get<bool>(this.Session, "LoggedIn");
        set => SessionHelper.SessionExtensions.Set<bool>(this.Session, "LoggedIn", value);
    }
}
```

and from my page model (Login.cshtml.cs) i am doing the following :

```
public void OnGet()
    {
        MySession.Instance.Session = HttpContext.Session;
    }
```

and i am accessing the session and storing and retrieving information perfectly as expected for example :

```
public ActionResult OnPostAuthenticate()
        {
            string username = Request.Form["username"];
            string password = Request.Form["password"];

            User user = this.userDataManager.GetUserAuthentication(username, password);

            if (user != null)
            {
                //authentication success

                //save session variables
                MySession.Instance.User = user;
                MySession.Instance.LoggedIn = true;

                return new JsonResult(new { success = true });
            }
            else
            {
                return new JsonResult(new { success = false });
            }
        }
```

And as i said everything work perfect, but i want to know if it is **SAFE** to use the session this way or my requests will be messed up and the same session information will be shared across all requests ?

Comment: It shouldn't be an issue, but having to remember to set the `Session` property is a code-smell.

Comment: I have not looked through this thoroughly, but it looks broken. As far as I can tell, there is only ever (at most) *one* session. If `UserA` accesses the site, then `UserB` also accesses the site before `UserA`'s request is done, then `UserA`'s session will be switched to `UserB`'s session while his request is still running.