# Using a session wrapper in ASP.Net Core Razor Pages

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

To improve the session handling in our application, we wanted to create a wrapper class which manages session access via properties (to prevent the common issues when working with strings).

Something like this:

```csharp
  public class Wrapper
  {
    public string Username
    {
      get { return HttpContext.Current.Session.GetString("username"); }
      set { HttpContext.Current.Session.SetString("username", value); }
    }
  }
```

There are quite a few examples of how to implement this in classic ASP.Net, but we weren't able to port them to ASP.Net Core. The only [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49303561/12730491) about a session wrapper in ASP.Net Core (that I could find) is using a Singleton, which we didn't find suitable for our case.

Our problem comes down to two main issues:

- How to wrap and access the current Session inside of another class properly (avoiding anti-patterns and security issues)
- How to share the class across our application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We decided to use the dependency injection functionality of ASP.Net Core, since it seemed perfectly suitable for the job. To access the session inside of a service the [IHttpContextAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1) is necessary. As stated in David Fowler's [ASP.NET Core Diagnostic Scenarios](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AspNetCoreGuidance.md#do-not-store-ihttpcontextaccessorhttpcontext-in-a-field) it is recommended to not store the `IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext` in a field, however using a [scoped service should mitigate this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59963920/12730491), since it gets [created for each request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#scoped).

### Our setup

Here we use the `HttpContextAccessor` to reference the current session. Access to the session is restricted through the use of properties (the strings could further be replaced with constants).

```csharp
  public class SessionService
  {
    private readonly ISession _session;

    public SessionService(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
      _session = accessor.HttpContext.Session;
    }

    public string Username
    {
      get { return _session.GetString("username"); }
      set { _session.SetString("username", value); }
    }
  }
```

The session wrapper then is configured as a scoped service inside of `Startup.cs`:

```csharp
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddRazorPages();
  // ...

  // Register the service we use for session handling.
  services.AddScoped<SessionService>();
}
```

Last but not least the service is injected into our page model and used to access the session through its property.

```csharp
  public class IndexModel : PageModel
  {
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
    private readonly SessionService _session;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, SessionService session)
    {
      _logger = logger;
      _session = session;
    }

    public void OnPost()
    {
      // Set the session variable.
      _session.Username = "foo@bar";
    }
  }
```

I am posting the answer in hopes of getting feedback on my solution and also providing a reference point for others struggling with this.

Comment: Why does the Typed Session need to be initialized? The untyped Session isn't, and static type checking happens at compile-time not runtime

Comment: @user1538301 Can you please elaborate? I am not sure what you mean with "Why does the Typed Session need to be initialized? The untyped Session isn't". Static type checking at compile-time is one of the reasons *why* we want to use a wrapper in the first place.

Comment: Actually, in retrospect it doesn't matter. This pattern works fine if you don't mind the added boilerplate (which I'm sure you've already weighed against its benefits). The main reason I was asking this is because you can get a `Session` from `HttpContext.Current.Session` so it seemed ideal to just use a property getter on a base class, but I suppose that's not available in all ASP.NET framework versions; just a little bit less boilerplate.

Comment: @user1538301 Ah yes. `HttpContext.Current` has been removed in ASP.Net Core. I think the `IHttpContextAccessor` is the only way to access the `HttpContext` inside the dependency injection system.

Comment: @m-code Ah. Yeah, that's what I figured. I was only so weary about it as I have seen a project that exposes a base class method that returns a typed session.. it was really messy (They called this method *everywhere* and never stored the results, they also didn't call it a `Session` they called it a `UserContext` which led me to believe they had implemented their own standalone storage mechanism in ASP.NET, only after digging into its source did I realize it was just a typed wrapper over `Session`)